# Remove CSS background border

Tags: css, background

Using a simple code, there's a kind of a "border" around the header background. How can I remove this?

```css
header {
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
 }
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Comment: what kind of border? you mean white-space around the page?

Comment: Yup, the awnser of @emmanuel solved it :)

Comment: use Normalize.css to makes the browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reset default `<body>` margin / padding.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
```

Comment: That's true but it is a common reset method.

Comment: Oh, thats all haha! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

It's just the default `margin` on `body`. It's generally a good idea to reset the `margin` and `padding` to 0 for all elements.